# How to change background colors in animation using python, plotly

Tags: python, plotly

I'm making a python program with plotly. I want to animate a square shape so that the blocks that it goes through change color, and I wish to set the background to a specific color pattern (fixed colors for each block until the animated square goes through it).

I'm new to plotly and I saw that there's a method to set the background color, but I want it to change with the animation (as explained above). I've looked at the docs but I can't understand them. I have already installed plotly in anaconda and I've written code that animates the square but doesn't change the background color. Would somebody please help me?

```
# "frames" is defined and given its value earlier in the code as a list of frames that draw squares like: go.Frame(data=[go.Scatter(x=[0,0,1,1,0], y=[0,1,1,0,0])]),

import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure(

    data=[go.Scatter(x=[1,1,2,2,1], y=[7, 8, 8, 7, 7],mode="lines",line=dict(color="red", width=2))],

    layout=go.Layout(
        xaxis=dict(range=[1, 8], autorange=False),
        yaxis=dict(range=[1, 9], autorange=False),
        title="Title",
        updatemenus=[dict(
            type="buttons",
            buttons=[dict(label="Play",
                          method="animate",
                          args=[None]),
                     dict(label="TestPause",
                          method="animate",
                          args=[[None], {"frame": {"duration": 0, "redraw": False},
                                  "mode": "immediate",
                                  "transition": {"duration": 0}}])])]
    ),
    frames=frames
)
```

I want the square to change the color of the blocks that it passed as if it were carrying a paintbrush, but I don't know how to do it.